# Dialog - send out

Tags: bash

how can i send apt-get install in dialogue i could answer the question (yes/no) ?

Something like:

```
apt-get install mc | dialog --progressbox 0 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, `expect` can help you.

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
>   according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be
>   expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An
>   interpreted language provides branching and high-level control
>   structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take
>   control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning
>   control to the script.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect